# ReactJS useMemo inside function

Tags: reactjs, react-usememo

I have this function:

```
const handleSearch = (event) => {
  const currentValue = event?.target?.value;
  const filteredData = searchTable(currentValue, originalData);
  setDataToTable(filteredData);
};
```

I tried to use `useMemo()` to memoize the value of `filteredData` in order to not perform the function `searchTable` because it's slow. I tried this inside the `handleSearch` function:

```
const filteredData = useMemo(() => searchTable(currentValue, originalData), [currentValue]);
```

But I get the `Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component` message which is correct.

How should I use `useMemo` for my case?

Comment: [Only call hooks at the top level.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level)

Comment: What you'd probably want instead is to memoize the `searchTable` function so that when you pass the same arguments you'll get the cached result.

Comment: I thought that I was doing that, I don't get you.

Comment: No, you're trying to memoize the return value, not the function itself, which is what I am suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must store the search query into a `state variable` and use `useMemo` with this variable to compute the filtered data.

```
function App() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState();
  const filteredData = useMemo(() => searchTable(query, originalData), [query]);
  
  function handleSearch(event) {
    setQuery(event?.target?.value);
  }

  return (...)
}
```

Comment: can we use 'useEffect(()=>{const filteredData = searchTable(currentValue, originalData);
  setDataToTable(filteredData);}, [query,originalData])' . what you gonna choose?

Comment: `searchTable` is being inmediatly called with `originalData` undefined

Comment: `useMemo` was typically created for this use case so I would use it. Your solution using `useEffect` would work but you need to declare another state variable `dataToTable`

Comment: where does `originalData` come from ? You didn't post all your code so it's difficult to guess how this variable is initialized